# Any reason for having a non-static class with static members only instead of making it static?

Tags: .net, private-constructor

I was in an interview yesterday and one of the questions was what is a singleton and how do you implement it.

[MSDN's implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Solution #1 from MSDN:

```
using System;

public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

I gave the simplest solution (solution number 1 from msdn's implementation), while he wanted the thread-safe one (solution number 3).

Solution #3 from MSDN:

```
using System;

public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static volatile Singleton instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null) 
                  instance = new Singleton();
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

What is intriguing me is the **private** constructor in msdn's example.
I did not know such a thing existed.

Taking a look at [msdn on it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcfb85a6.aspx)

```
public class Counter
{
    private Counter() { }
    public static int currentCount;
    public static int IncrementCount()
    {
        return ++currentCount;
    }
}
```

I then ask:

Why would you have a class that has only static members and thus would like to prevent instances of it being created and hence the use for a private constructor - instead of making the class static ?!

**P.S**.: **The question is not about singletons** - is about describing a scenario where I would choose to create an instantiable class that has static members only (and thus eventually creating the need for a private constructor) instead of using a static class.

Comment: Singleton examples generally concentrate on "the code that's responsible for initializing the singleton" - in reality you *would* have instance members, and sometimes it would implement an interface.

Comment: The real answer you should have given him is, that you shouldn't bother with implementing Singletons, and instead use the IOC container to control the lifetime of the object.

Comment: I do wonder why people still ask questions about singletons in programming interviews.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: maybe it tells something about the place the candidate is applying to - and he/she should reflect about it :-)

Comment: @Veverke - Please don't link to external sources unless it is to support content already in your question. We never know when external links will break and render the question useless.

Comment: @Enigmativity: fair enough.

Answer (score 4):

> Why would you have a class that has only static members and thus would
>   like to prevent instances of it being created and hence the use for a
>   private constructor - instead of making the class static

The main difference between using a singleton over a static class is that you can implement interfaces on the former, and pass it around as such without binding to the concrete implementation detail of the singelton, while a static class cannot.

Other than that, the singleton instance variables need to be static and can be exposed as regular instance members.

Comment: Thanks Yuval, but I see all the comments are relating to singletons... although the topic developed from it, the question is about something else - why would I ever want an instantiable class to have only static members (and thus create the possibility for needing a private constructor) instead of having a static class ? So your answer applies as well ? Because I would be interested in having that class implement interfaces, and static classes cannot ?

Comment: I generally think that'd you'd almost never want to have an instance method with only static members, that makes little sense. Private constructors will be used in places where you don't want the user to explicitly be able to create an instance. It can be a singleton, it can be some sort of factory on the object itself (I'm not sure the object should create it's own instance, but that happens sometimes).

Comment: Giving you +1 for the comment above, which is the one that relates to the question posed. Thanks.